# How to save Image or Graphics in Terminal?

Tags: export, linux, java, external-calls, save

In my Linux computer,it can't save `Image` or `Graphics` to picture format such as `png,jpg,tiff,pdf...` but `txt` is OK

```
p=Graphics@Circle[];
Export["test.jpg",p];(*always calculating*)
```

I want to know is there something alternative way to save picture like using `JLink`?

[image]

**System**

> Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
>
> Description:   Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
>
> Release:   14.04
>
> Codename:  trusty

I try this code but no image file found.

```
<< JLink`;
InstallJava[];
outputfile = JavaNew["java.io.File", "test.png"];
img = RandomImage[1, {20, 10}, ColorSpace -> "RGB"];
{h, w} = ImageDimensions[img];
src = JavaNew["java.awt.image.BufferedImage", w, h,BufferedImage`TYPEUINTURGB];
LoadJavaClass["javax.imageio.ImageIO"];
ImageIO@write[src, "PNG", outputfile]
```

Do I need install some package?

**Update:**

In my another Linux machine,it raise error.

[image]

Using romote kernel from mathematica,it's OK.

[image]

***Thank you @Szabolcs.***

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb
xvfb-run wolfram
```

***Then it can export Graphics or Image!***

Comment: This should not really happen. You are saying that `Export` does not work on Linux?  That will be a major bug if this was the case. But what does `Directory[]` say before you issue the command?

Comment: It works on my Xubuntu. What specific distro are you using, and what version of *Mathematica*?

Comment: @J.M. 11.1.1 version

Comment: Thanks for the video. It fails because you are using `TimeConstrained` 

This is expected. If operation do not complete in the time gives, it will abort.

So what you have to do, is remove the `TimeConstrained` It looks like it needs more than one second to do the export. Any reason why you are using `TimeConstrained` by the way?  Here is an example `TimeConstrained[NextPrime[1000], 0.0001]` which gives `$Aborted`

Comment: @Nasser Using `TimeConstrained` just explained this problem, so I used that function.Even for ten minutes, it could not export it.I can't record gif for long time, so I used one second. – partida 32 mins ago

Comment: Why are you using the command line?  Is there an X server running? That's required for exporting on Linux.

Comment: @Szabolcs But in Raspberry pi,it can export even no X server running

Comment: Perhaps you are not aware that an X server is connected.  It is not possible to export *graphics* without one.  If you use a remote machine, then you can either forward X using `ssh -X` / `ssh -Y` or use Xfvb.

Comment: But Export does not use the graphical interface, why the server be open? In python,Export is directly feasible

Comment: Graphics are rendered by the front end, not the kernel. The Linux version of the front end cannot run without an X server.  Common solutions are X forwarding, Xvfb or Xvnc.  You may be having the last one of these already running on your Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @Szabolcs Well done. Thank you! `sudo apt-get install xvfb` then `xvfb-run 
 wolfram`,everything is OK!!!